Parse the output of a linux command
I'm trying to match one specific line to capture an address in the output of a bridge control command on a remote host.  I'm not sure if this should be done using stdout and readlines. I'm a noob...
import paramiko
import re

hostname = "192.168.88.79"
port = 22
username = "admin"
password = "password"


def lan0_mac():
    s = paramiko.SSHClient()
    s.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    s.connect(hostname, port, username, password)
    command = "brctl showmacs br0"
    stdin, stdout, stderr = s.exec_command(command)
    for line in stdout.readlines():
        mac = re.search(r'1\s{5}(([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}))\s{7}no', line).group(1)
        print (mac)
    s.close()


lan0_mac()

I'm getting:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/user/bridgetable.py", line 22, in <module>
lan0_mac()
File "/home/user/bridgetable.py", line 17, in lan0_mac
mac = re.search(r'1\s{5}(([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}))\s{7}no', line).group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Here is the sample output:
port no mac addr                is local?       ageing timer

  2     24:5a:4c:34:xx:xx       no                13.74

  2     24:5a:4c:34:xx:xx       no                 7.96

  2     24:5a:4c:34:xx:xx       no                 0.88

  2     24:5a:4c:34:xx:xx       no                 0.05

  2     24:5a:4c:34:xx:xx       yes                0.00

  1     24:5a:4c:34:xx:xx       yes                0.00

  2     24:5a:4c:34:xx:xx       no                 5.52

  2     24:5a:4c:34:xx:xx       no                 0.57

  2     24:5a:4c:34:xx:xx       no                15.76

  1     50:d4:f7:5e:xx:xx       no                 7.97

  2     24:5a:4c:34:xx:xx       no                 0.42

  2     24:5a:4c:34:xx:xx       no                22.09

  2     24:5a:4c:34:xx:xx       no                 9.48

  2     24:5a:4c:34:xx:xx       no                 1.16


This means your regex did not match. This can only be answered if you post your full error traceback (guessable here, but you must do that for any question where your code errors) and full command output (stdout.readlines(), you may save it to a variable, print and loop only after that). It's a regex question - you need to figure out what you're trying to match and why the regex does not do that.

As @STerliakov notes we need the info requested to help you.   I will note that you are looping over all the lines.  unless its a single line of output you will have many lines that do not match and return null.   you probably want to save the result of the search and test if null if not null then get the group capture and return it.

Taking your code and modifying it assuming it is getting multiple lines of output:
import paramiko
import re

hostname = "192.168.88.79"
port = 22
username = "admin"
password = "password"


def lan0_mac():
    s = paramiko.SSHClient()
    s.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    s.connect(hostname, port, username, password)
    command = "brctl showmacs br0"
    stdin, stdout, stderr = s.exec_command(command)
    for line in stdout.readlines():
        test_result = re.search(r'1\s{5}(([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}))\s{7}no', line)
        if test_result:
            mac = test_result.group(1)
            print (mac)
    s.close()


lan0_mac()


Note you should check for failures to connect, etc in the real world.

Yes multiple lines of output. No error now, but it's not printing the match. I'll try to figure out what's going on with that. So removing the group from the regex search and adding it to a variable resolved the issue?

checking for null result returned from search (indicates no match found).   So I would find an online Regex tester,  get sample output and see if your regex string actually can capture the mac correctly.

If you can add sample output we might be able to help work through the regex with you.

I already made sure it matched on RegExr, I'll add the sample if you want to check it out.

I tried adding the sample. It looked fine in the message body but the formatting got chewed up after post.

Looks like someone may have fixed that formating.  I just checked the regex and the capture group looks good.  did that get you going?  looks like you accepted the answer so hope it helped..

on final thing.  great site here for regex that lets folks put in sample data and will generate sample code for the test (just adding here for completeness):  https://regex101.com/

Yes, I've used both 'regex101.com' and 'regexr.com' but I'm still missing something. I can match all mac addresses in the output without a problem but when I try to match only the line with port '1' and local 'no' I cannot get a match.

have you tried printing your lines before the regex test to make sure the command is running correctly and producing output properly?

Printing the original output without regex works just fine. That is how I provided the sample text. I can match just the mac address from all lines, but no match when I try the mac from one single line e.g., '1     50:d4:f7:5e:f7:ff       no'. Maybe it has to do with the whitespace characters?

@notsure that would be my best guess based your prior responses.   Tabs v spaces ?

It works! There was a problem matching the whitespace characters. Instead of the exact quantifier, I had to use 1 or more. Thank you very much for all of your help!
